# fat free framework template date formatting

Tags: date, template-engine, fat-free-framework

I have a DateTime field in mysql. Using a .ini file with this code:

```
_dateformat = {0,date,custom,%m-%d-%Y}
```

I can change the printed format of MyDate depending on the loaded language .ini by using this in my template:

```
{{@_dateformat,strtotime(@MyDate) |format}}
```

I'm now trying to find a way to display only the full month name from that date. 
I tried these options (looking at the ICU-project specs)

```
_monthname = {0,date,custom,%M} (up to four M's)
_monthname = {0,date,custom,%L} (up to four L's)
_monthname = {0,date,custom,%F} (displays the date in yyyy-mm-dd format)
```

But nothing returns the month name.

How can I display only the month name of a date, language specific, in fat free framework using the template engine?

Comment: `{0,date,custom,%B}` should do it. See [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)'s format.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.